# Plupload sending files to a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, service, web, plupload

I want to use plupload to send two files to a webservice. The service expects to see two files of the xsd type, it should also receive the files in a way that the first input field is named  "sourceSchema" and the second input field is called "targetSchema".

I would appreciate if I can get any clarification of how plupload send these files, can I rename the input field. How does it submit the form ?

my code is:

```
// Setup html5 version
$("#html5_uploader").pluploadQueue({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'html5',
    url : schemaMatchingUrl,
    unique_names : true,
    filters : [ {
        title : "Excel sheets",
        extensions : "xls,csv,xlsx"
    }, {
        title : "XSD files",
        extensions : "xsd"
    } ],

// Resize images on clientside if we can
resize : {
    width : 320,
    height : 240,
    quality : 90
},
init : {
    FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
      plupload.each(files, function(file) {
        if (up.files.length > 2) {
            alert("Sorry .. Maximum two files are allowed !!");
          up.removeFile(file);
        }
      });
      if (up.files.length >= 2) {
        $('#pickfiles').hide('slow');
      }
    },
    FilesRemoved: function(up, files) {
      if (up.files.length < 2) {
        $('#pickfiles').fadeIn('slow');
      }
    }
  },
  multi_selection: false
});
```